# Child theme of child theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am developing a website based on child theme, itself based on the framework "Cherry".

I am considering what would be the best way to customize this child theme. I will most likely just have to perform minor modifications like css updates. I am contemplating:

- Creating a child theme of the child theme (I tried it, but wordpress told me my child theme was invalid as a parent-theme)
- Working on a copy of my child theme (like child theme - dev).

Does anyone know what would be the best solution, or the pro and cons of each ?

Comment: Research for "wordpress grandchild theme"

Comment: I did it already. According to some info it is not possible to do grandchild themes. If anyone has more info on this, that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You'll find WP Devs at [wordpress.se], but put your research in the table, because you didn't even mention the term *grandchild* in the question...

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit confused. I can see that I can post my questions both here and on the subdomain wordpress.stackoverflow. Should I post my questions only on this subdomain from now on ?

Comment: An italian web developer solved it by creating a plugin, [here is her tutorial](http://www.gloriaingrassia.com/grandchild-theme-via-plugin/). I'm sorry if the text is italian, but schemas and snippets are very clear so you can get some clues.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to work on a copy of the child theme since grandchild themes are just a pain. If you're really interested in grandchild themes, here's [at least one way that it can be accomplished](https://wordpress.tv/2016/02/18/bobbie-wilson-grandchild-themes-for-framework-child-themes/) but in this case you essentially end up writing an a plugin to do handle it.